# Linking to another app from my app using address

Tags: android, android-intent

At the moment we have a tool that has addresses on it, and we use Co Pilot on the phones to navigate to these locations. I see the autotrader app when you click the address lets you select what application would you like to open this address with and includes copilot / google maps etc.

However I can't for the life of me work out what sort of intent you'd launch from the address to give the option to load co-pilot.

I could be explaining this very badly, but any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean about "address" what kind of address?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the correct `Uri` for your intent. It will also depend if there's any other app in the device that registers for that specific `Uri`, like clicking a `http://...` link in your email will ask you which of the installed browsers should handle it. Google maps uses the geo `Uri` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html). I haven't used this in a long time, but seing that the page is till up these may still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lats and longs set the `Intent` to use `ACTION_DEFAULT` like shown in the code below. It will give you an option to choose if there is more than one maps application

```
            String uri = String.format("geo:%f,%f", 2.345, -3.125323);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
```

This works for me